# Laravel increment

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having problem with increment.
I have query in model.

```
public function scopeViewCount($query)
{
    return $query->increment('view', 1);
}
```

My controller.

```
public function quoteBySlug($slug)
{
    $quote = Article::bySlug($slug);
            
    if (! $quote) {
        abort(404);
    }
            
    $quote->viewCount();
            
    return view('pages/quote/quote-detailed')->with('quote', $quote);
}
```

Its working but problem is that its adding +2 some times even +4 but i need only +1 so what's i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using scopes wrong. Scopes is for define common sets of query constraints, see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes).

Than, just remove `scope` prefix:

```
public function incrementViewCount()
    {
        return $this->increment('view', 1);
    }

$quote->incrementViewCount();
```

Comment: It was adding +2 or  +4  because of query?

Comment: Its because laravel magic - laravel can call scope much times behind the scene.

Comment: aa okay thanks )